# Google Cloud Storage upload conflict from web UI

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, macos-mojave

Just recently in the last few days, whenever I use the Google Cloud web interface in Chrome to upload a file into a Storage bucket, I am seeing:

[image]

I confirm the file **DOES NOT exist** in the bucket, it is a random file id name. Uploading files into this bucket from Chrome worked just as recently as last week. I don't think I changed anything related to the bucket. I believe I have updated my browser Google Chrome *(69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit))* and macOS to Mojave though.

Anybody else confirm?

**UPDATE: I was able to upload a file from Firefox successfully to the same bucket *(62.0.3 (64-bit))*, so it seems to be a regression in Google Chrome 69 which is sort of ironic.**

Comment: I just tried uploading a file via the web interface, using Chrome version 69.0.3497.95, and I didn't see this problem. Does it happen for all files or is there some specific way to repro the problem?

Comment: I am just creating a blank file in terminal `touch sskdf9urewhdsf.png` and then dragging from my macOS desktop into the Storage bucket Chrome tab.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a new user/profile in your current Chrome and testing in that.  This would allow us to determine if there is some plugin or other artifact configured in the instance of Chrome you are using that might be interfering with the transfer.

Comment: I went into Incognito mode and uploading worked as expected without conflict. Can you recommend steps to correct?

Answer (score 0):

Uploading to Storage in Chrome now magically works. I believe the error was due to AdBlocker which recently pushed an update. Perhaps AdBlocker was the culprit.